# Productsigned Mac app not installing in computers that are not mine

Tags: macos, installation, certificate, package, osx-gatekeeper

I have a Mac app which I have signed using the 'productsign' command from the terminal

```
productsign --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: My company (dasdfjkaj)" InstallerUnsigned.pkg InstallerSigned.pkg

productsign: signing product with identity "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: My company (dasdfjkaj)" from keychain /Users/me/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
productsign: adding intermediate certificate "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority"
productsign: Wrote signed product archive to InstallerSigned.pkg
```

I then ran the assess command

```
spctl -a -v --type install  InstallerSigned.pkg
InstallerSigned.pkg: accepted
```

I also checked the signature

```
pkgutil --check-signature InstallerSigned.pkg 
Package "InstallerSigned.pkg":
Status: signed by a developer certificate issued by Apple
   Certificate Chain:
    1. 3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: My company (dasdfjkaj)
    2. Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
    3. Apple Root CA
```

When I run the installer from my machine (with Gatekeeper set to "Mac App store and identified developers") it runs fine. It also installed properly when I downloaded the same pkg after I deployed it to my website.

But... when I download the pkg in another machine it fails to install. It does not recognize my developer ID. When I run the spctl command on the failed machine, I get

```
spctl -a -v --type install  InstallerSigned.pkg
InstallerSigned.pkg: rejected
```

Does anyone know why this it runs fine on my own machine but fails when the pkg runs on another machine? I am all out of ideas really :/

EDIT:
This is what I get when

```
spctl --list --type execute
3[Apple System] P0 allow execute
    anchor apple
4[Mac App Store] P0 allow execute
    anchor apple generic and certificate leaf[field.<I removed this>] exists
5[Developer ID] P0 allow execute
    anchor apple generic and certificate 1[field.<I removed this>] exists and certificate leaf[field.<I removed this>] exists
7[GKE] P0 allow execute [(gke)]
    cdhash H"<I removed this>"
10[GKE] P0 allow execute [(gke)]
    cdhash H"<I removed this>"
14[GKE] P0 allow execute [(gke)]
    cdhash H"<I removed this>"
15[GKE] P0 allow execute [(gke)]
    cdhash H"<I removed this>"
18[GKE] P0 allow execute [(gke)]
```

Comment: what's the output look like when you use `spctl --list --type execute`

Comment: `spctl -a -v --type execute InstallerSigned.pkg`
`InstallerSigned.pkg: rejected`

Comment: I have added `spctl --list --type execute` results in the main post. I got 868 [GKE] things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Certificates Matter

These are the certificates you will need to use together for codesigning:

- **Developer ID Installer**
- **Developer ID Application**

  - **3rd Party Mac Developer Installer** (usually only used for the AppStore apps).

The "**Developer ID Installer**" certificate is what you would use if not submitting to the AppStore. For codesigning portions specifically, you need to use the "**Developer ID Application**" certificate.

[**Apple Developer Codesigning Workflow Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH12-SW2)

Comment: When I go to the Apple developer site, the only options I see under https://developer.apple.com/account/mac/certificate/certificateCreate.action is `Apple Push Notification service SSL (Production)` and `Website Push ID Certificate`
Also, my project is made in Unity3D and not in Xcode.

Comment: @Djokovic, If you don't have them you'll need to request them using `XCode > Preferences > Accounts`. Since you don't use XCode you can probably do that through the developer portal.

Comment: The important thing for your particular scenario is "Make sure you sign the installer package using your Developer ID Installer certificate. The productsign command-line utility allows you to sign an installer package using your Developer ID Application certificate. Although this approach may appear to work, the resulting installer archive will fail on the destination Mac"

Comment: I don't see any "Accounts" under `XCode > Preferences`. Also, where is the developer portal?  (Thanks for replying so fast!)

Comment: Which XCode are you using? In XCode 5+ it's under Preferences > Accounts (2nd Button). Then click the + sign at the bottom.

Comment: I did see the warning about using Application certificate, but I am still in the dark on how to get a Developer ID Installer certificate :/

Comment: I am using XCode 4.3.3

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45846/discussion-between-djokovic-and-lll)